# Cannot inject property for singleton

Tags: objective-c, typhoon

I use Typhoon framework for injections in VIPER architecture. I created 2 modules and used presenters of each modules for them connections. Presenter of module B had `definition.scope = TyphoonScopeWeakSingleton`. But it couldn't inject its property. Presenter A had reference to it and view B had too.

```
-(StatsVC*)statsView
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[StatsVC class]
                          configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition)
            {
                [definition  injectProperty:@selector(presenter) with:[self statsPresenter]];
            }];
}

-(OTStatsPresenter*)statsPresenter
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[OTStatsPresenter class]
                          configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition* definition)
            {
                [definition  injectProperty:@selector(view) with:[self statsView]];
                definition.scope = TyphoonScopeWeakSingleton;
            }];
}
```

how to inject that?